# React Perf : what does it mean to have "Connect(componentName) in printWasted?

Tags: performance, reactjs, perf

I am using React Perf tools to find out wasted rendering/cycles. ([react-addons-perf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-perf))

**I see lot of Connect(component-name) in the list. What does that mean?**

Incidentally all these Connects are those where **I have passed null as a parameter.** (I don't need to use mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProps). But to use 'dispatch' functionality, I do have to pass null as a parameter to connect.

```
export default connect(null)(FacilityCard);
```

How can i save this time wasted?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use connect when you're not passing a redux state to your props, or dispatch methods to your props?

Comment: @SeanKwon : Yes I need to dispatch a method. I am using it like this :
this.props.dispatch(updateSearchParams({
            selectedAmenityList: tempArray
        }));

Comment: you're better off using mapdispatchtoprops like so: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ updateSearchParams: (amenityList) => dispatch(updateSearchParams(amenityList))})` What you're doing isn't wrong, but it's good to decouple your redux actions from your components. Is there a special reason you're ignoring mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: No there is not special reason I did that, it's just more easy and quick to use and implement :)

Answer (score 0):

It means the `connect` High-Order-Component is the one that is doing wasted rendering.
I've found that upgrading `react-redux` to version 5 (5.0.3 as of this answer) solve the problem is wasted rendering due to `connect`.